# Construir script en Perl para que a medida que se insertan datos en un archivo log, se obtengan y procesen instantaneamente

Tags: linux, perl

Colegas estoy haciendo un script en perl para que a medida que se insertan datos en un archivo log, instantaneamente obtenerlos y procesarlos pero me esta dando un error (el error es en el open) y no se que hacer.
les paso el codigo:

```
#######!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Shell;   

 my $logfile = "...";  
 my $run;  

 open $run, ("tail -f $logfile") or die " El fichero $logfile no tiene datos" and exit;  

 while (<$run>) {  
    ...  
 }

close ($run);
```

ERROR:

> El fichero .... no tiene datos at ... line 9.

Nota. El log si contiene datos y esta si me lo lee pero no sigue en ejecucion esperando datos nuevos:

```
open $run, $logfile or die " El fichero $logfile no tiene datos" and exit;
```

Comment: De `perl`, ni idea; pero `tail -f ...` **no es un archivo**, es un comando, y no creo que `open` se pensara para eso. Lo que debes haces en un bucle, comprobando el tamaño del archivo, y, si este cambia, leer los nuevos datos. Y usar alguna clase de temporizador, para comprobar cada segundo (o varios segundos), o alguna clase de *file watcher* que te informe de cambios sin tener que comprobarlo tú.

Comment: la variable $logfile tiena la direccion del archivo y vi una vez un ejemplo con open pero no pedo comunicarme con esa pers

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que buscas. Está en inglés, pero el código es *universal* ;-) [How do I read a file which is constantly updating?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425292)

Answer (score 1):

En CPAN encontrarás módulos para hacer eso, como el caso de [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ATail)

Ejemplo:

```
use File::Tail;

my $archivo = File::Tail->new("/ruta/al/archivo.log");
while (defined(my $linea = $archivo->read)) {
    print $linea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos por su ayuda
aqui les dejo como me quedo al final

```
open (my $run, "tail -F -n +1 $logfile|") or die " El fichero $logfile no tiene datos" and exit;
```

Comment: Recomiendo que edites la pregunta  y agregues tu actualizacion